# Why does one instance of my button class work but not another?

Tags: c#, xna

I have a button class named `CraftButton` which has a variable called `isClicked`, and in another class i make 2 instances of the `Button` class like so:
`Button b1, b2;`

I also have a method called `FunctionizeButtons` which is used to check if i have clicked the buttons:

```
if (bP1.isClicked)
        {
            Game1.Instance.examineString = "button 1";
        }

        if (b2.isClicked)
        {
            Game1.Instance.examineString = "button2";
        }
```

But as i try the buttons, only the b1 responds.
The `isClicked` variable doesn't work on the b2, but on b1, why is that?

My button class:

```
public class CraftButton
{

    public Texture2D _texNormal, _texPushed, _texHighlighted, currentTex;
    public Vector2 position;
    Rectangle rectangle;

    public bool isPushed = false;
    public bool isClicked = false;



    public CraftButton(ContentManager Content)
    {
        _texNormal = Content.Load<Texture2D>("UI/button");
        _texPushed = Content.Load<Texture2D>("UI/buttonPushed");
        _texHighlighted = Content.Load<Texture2D>("UI/buttonHighlighted");
        rectangle = new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, _texNormal.Width, _texNormal.Height);
        currentTex = _texNormal;
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        rectangle = new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, _texNormal.Width, _texNormal.Height);

        if (rectangle.Contains(Game1.Instance.mPoint))
            currentTex = _texHighlighted;
        else
            currentTex = _texNormal;

        if (Game1.Instance.mState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && rectangle.Contains(Game1.Instance.mPoint))
        {
            currentTex = _texPushed;
            isPushed = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isPushed = false;
        }

        if (Game1.Instance.mState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && Game1.Instance.oldMstate.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released && rectangle.Contains(Game1.Instance.mPoint))
        {
            isClicked = true;
        }
        else
            isClicked = false;

        Game1.Instance.oldMstate = Game1.Instance.mState;
    }



    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(currentTex, position, Color.White);
    }
}
```

}

What i mean with it doesn't work, is the `b2`'s `isClicked` variable is constantly false, it doesn't react to being clicked on as the `b1` does.

I'm really confused and would love some help, thanks!

Comment: I don't see any code referencing a `b1`.

Comment: Show the relevant source of your `Button` class and explain what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: Updated my post, tell me if you need more :)

Comment: `if (bP1.isClicked)` - is that a _typo_?

Comment: You update the 'Game1.Instance.oldMstate' inside your Button class. This means that after the first update is being ran, the remaining ones will have the new mouse state set as the Old. This means that 'Game1.Instance.oldMstate.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released' will fail on subsequent runs.